# How can I use jQuery to submit a form without refreshing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

i have this form:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="shout-in" id="proShoutIn" maxlength="80" />
<a href="#" id="add_shout"><img src="post.gif"/></a>
</form>
```

how can i do a ajax post so that i can use `if (isset($_POST['shout-in'])){..do something..}`?
i need to get the value that gets entered in the `<input>` and do a post with it.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#add_shout').click(function () {
    var $form=$('#myform');
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize());
});
```

- [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - `$.ajax()` shorthand for the POST method
- [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) - creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation

With the 3rd (optional) parameter of `$.post()` you can specify a callback function which will receive anything that was sent back as its only parameter. It will run when the AJAX query successfully finished (so you can do DOM modifications that depend on the AJAX call, etc.).

You also might want to prevent default form submission (in a lot of browsers pressing Enter in the input field would trigger it) and run the AJAX submission:

```
$('#myform').submit(function (e) {
     $('#add_shout').click();
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: and where do i fit this php `if (isset($_POST['shout-in'])){...}`

Comment: @Patrioticcow What I've given you is the Javascript (jQuery) code. That PHP line you've written should go into your `test.php`.

Comment: what if the php is in the same file? will that be a problem?

Comment: and shall i use `if (isset($_POST['shout-in'])){...}` or `if (isset($_POST)){...}` ?

Comment: @Patrioticcow using `if (isset($_POST['shout-in'])){...}` is right. Normally it is not a problem if they are in the same file, if you handle it the right way. For cleaner code, you should separate your Javascript into a `.js` file and include it with `<script src="xy.js">` (becomes much easier to debug and change in the long run).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("test.php", $("#myform").serialize(),
    function(data) {
      // do something with the response
    }
);
```

Comment: and where do i fit this php `if (isset($_POST['shout-in'])){...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
      $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
         //handle response
      });
      //prevent form from submitting.  In jQuery, do not use return false
      e.preventDefault();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nettuts plus:

[Submit A Form Without Page Refresh using jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)